# CodeIgniter loading a view

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, view

A function in the controller `User` loads the signup form, eg:

```
public function signup()
    {
        $this->load->view('form_view'); 
    }
```

So the signup form url will be like `root/user/signup`  (ignore index.php)

The `form_view` has a form, which is submitted to another method in the same controller, lets say `process()`, eg.

```
<? echo form_open('user/process') ?>
```

Once the form is submitted, it goes to the `user/process`, which contains the validation code. If there is any validation error, It would load the `form_view` again and pass the error data to display on the form.

```
if ( $this -> form_validation -> run() === FALSE )
{
    //$this -> load -> vars( $data );
    $this -> load -> view( 'form_view' );   

}
```

Everything works fine. But now since the same `form_view` is loaded from the `user/process` function, the url of the form will change from:

```
root/user/signup
```

to

```
root/user/process
```

Because the form was submitted to the url `user/process` and the `form_view` is being called from the `process()`. Is it possible to somehow redirect or maintain the original form url(`root/user/signup`) when the `form_view` is loaded from the process function in case of errors?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd use the method in the CI docs, which will keep the original URL, but not post to another method in your controller http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#thecontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same method to for and validation you can try something like

```
if( count($this->input->post()) > 0 ) 
{ // do validation
   if ($this->form_validation->run())
   {
       // initilize and    
       redirect('logged');
   }
}
$this->load->view( 'form_view' );
```

you always get the same method, as you asked

Comment: Thanks. Just wondering why `count($this->input->post()) > 0`, would this also be fine? `if( $this->input->post() ) ` ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The function returns FALSE (boolean) if there are no items in the POST. You can also check for the existence of one of the fields, let's say $this->input->post('username') with the same results.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this a different way. I actually have one controller to do all this.

```
if ( $this -> form_validation -> run() === TRUE )
{
    code
    code
    redirect('ANOTHER_URL_WITH_VALIDATION_CODE_DISPLAY');        
}

$this -> load -> view( 'form_view' );
```

Sorry about that, I meant to say one controller NOT one method. If you're just looking for form validation, then throw it all into one controller. Have CI's built-in form_validation function do the validation for you. IF you require backend validation (i.e. username check), you can create a custom validation rule called a "[callback](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks)" and have the form validate against that as well.

Ideally your controller will check all fields, if it passes, it should redirect to onward to the next page w/ any information you want to display (i.e. "Thank's for registering!"). If it fails the check, it should load the view page again; you'll need to repopulate the fields obviously.

Comment: I think that's merely a comment.

Comment: @luckytaxi can you give some more info please? Did you mean i should use only one controller function to load the default form and the same function to load the function with validation erros? Could you give some example of how you did? thanks.

Comment: @Roman, See Nick's comment. Its exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

See my response here for a detailed explanation of how/why the Codeigniter form validation should be called:

[Question about how redirects should work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761271/question-about-how-redirects-should-work/5813341#5813341)